# Python : Graph suggesting path with minimum number of paths

Tags: python, graph

[image: Image for describing the test case of problem statement]

I have implemented [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Python) and modified it.For the given graph If need to get shortest path from A to F getting

> A --(R2,R4)-->M --(R2,R4)-->N --(R3)-->L --(R3)-->F

With the modified code or other way what I am interested in is minimum number of routes , so in this case as have direct route R1 output should be

> A --(R1)--> B --(R1)-->C --(R1)-->D --(R1)-->E--(R1)-->F

Can some one suggest how can we get that. Assuming distance between routes is same. Here is my code for it. 
[Fiddle Code for minimum routes](http://pythonfiddle.com/minimum-routes-problem/)

Comment: I don't understand your question. The picture is **not** a graph. Can you define what you mean by path and route in that thing?

Comment: Path is the route here , R1 : [A,B,C,D,E,F] is a path. path and route are same. Suppose them as bus stops on particular route for transit. Thanks

Comment: Also please have a look at the code running for above diagram finding path between A to F http://pythonfiddle.com/minimum-routes-problem/  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the graph so there will be an edge from each early vertex on a route to a later one (change lines 49-51 in the linked code):

```
for route,path in routes.iteritems():
    for i in range(len( path)-1):
        for j in range(i, len(path)):
            data.append( (path[i] , path[j] , 1 , route))
```

That outputs:

```
For  A to F  : > 
(('A', 'F'), ['R1'])
```

If you wish to expand the route back you can modify the print code to:

```
print "For  A to F  : > "
for (s,d),r in  find_shortest_path("A","F"):
    b = False
    for i in range(len(routes[r[0]])):
        v = routes[r[0]][i]
        if v == s:
            b = True
        elif v == d:
            break
        if b:
           print((v, routes[r[0]][i+1]), r)
```

And that outputs:

```
For  A to F  : > 
(('A', 'B'), ['R1'])
(('B', 'C'), ['R1'])
(('C', 'D'), ['R1'])
(('D', 'E'), ['R1'])
(('E', 'F'), ['R1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace multi-edges with one weight edge, weight being number of edges.

Then do the Dijkstra algorithm on it. In you example graph weight of your **desired path is going to be 5**, and the path that Dijkstra algorithm on **unweighted graph returns is going to be 6**.